# Trying to find the Max and min position of the images in VB, it keeps giving the last position only

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Structure website
    Public imagename As String
    Public publisher As String
    Public views As Integer
    Public dislikes As Integer
    Public likes As Integer
End Structure

Public Class Form1
    'declaring variables
    Private images() As website
    Private k As Integer
    Private dislikes As Integer
    Private totallikes As Integer
    Private totalviews As Integer
    Private totaldislikes As Integer
    Private average As Double
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'input the number of images
        k = CInt(InputBox("input the number of images"))
        Placeresults(0, 1, "Views")
        Placeresults(0, 2, "Likes")
        Placeresults(0, 3, "Dislikes")
        Placeresults(0, 4, " Publisher Name")
        ReDim images(k) 'Resizing array 
        grd.Rows = k + 2

        Dim x As Integer
        For x = 1 To k


        Next x
        Placeresults(k + 1, 0, "Total")



    End Sub
    'creating subroutines
    Private Sub Placeresults(ByVal r As Integer, ByVal c As Integer, ByVal t As String)
        grd.Row = r
        grd.Col = c
        grd.Text = t
    End Sub

    Private Sub btninput_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btninput.Click
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To k
            images(k).imagename = CStr(InputBox("The name of image number " & CStr(i)))
            Placeresults(i, 0, CStr((images(k).imagename)))
            images(k).views = CInt(InputBox("input no. of views for image  " & CStr(i)))
            images(k).likes = CInt(InputBox("input the number of likes for image" & CStr(i)))
            images(k).publisher = CStr(InputBox("input the name of the publisher for image" & CStr(i)))
            Placeresults(i, 1, CStr(images(k).views))
            Placeresults(i, 4, CStr(images(k).publisher))
            Placeresults(i, 2, CStr(images(k).likes))
            dislikes = images(k).views - images(k).likes
            Placeresults(i, 3, CStr(dislikes))
            totallikes = images(k).likes + totallikes
            totalviews = images(k).views + totalviews
            totaldislikes = dislikes + totaldislikes
        Next i
        Placeresults(k + 1, 1, CStr(totalviews))
        Placeresults(k + 1, 2, CStr(totallikes))
        Placeresults(k + 1, 3, CStr(totaldislikes))
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnaverage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnaverage.Click
        average = totalviews / k
        Txtaverage.Text = CStr(average)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim max, maxindex, i As Integer
        max = images(1).likes
        maxindex = 1
        For i = 1 To k
            If max < images(i).likes Then
                max = images(i).likes
                maxindex = i
            End If
        Next i
        MsgBox("image " & CStr(images(k).imagename) & " has the Most likes with" & CStr(max))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim min, j, minindex As Integer
        minindex = 1
        min = images(1).dislikes
        For j = 1 To k
            If j > images(j).dislikes Then
                j = images(j).dislikes
                minindex = j
            End If
        Next j
        MsgBox("image" & CStr(images(k).imagename) & "has the most dislikes with " & CStr(min))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This question is a mess, i couldn't even edit it before I'm not even sure of the question you are asking, or even if it is giving you an error, I want to help you but i need more information and a cleaner question, only use the code that it is failing on.

Comment: Your problem is in your MsgBox - where you do images(k).imagename - k is the loop variable and will be the last value.  You meatn images(maxindex).imagename

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here **[ask]** and it's also important to look here .. **[mcve]** .. **Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Comment: @Werdna I know my coding sucks, but I was tryna find the name of the image with the highest likes and dislikes at a specific position

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse it is still giving the last position as the answer

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues Your MessageBox should refer to `maxindex` as instead of `J` or `K`. Also in the code to find the Min, you're changing the loop index and not `Min`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles  Button1.Click
    Dim max, maxindex, i As Integer
    max = images(1).likes
    maxindex = 1
    For i = 1 To k
        If max < images(i).likes Then
            max = images(i).likes
            maxindex = i
         End If
     Next i
     MsgBox("image " & CStr(images(k).imagename) & " has the Most likes with" & CStr(max))
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim min, j, minindex As Integer
    minindex = 1
    min = images(1).dislikes
    For j = 1 To k
        If j > images(j).dislikes Then
            j = images(j).dislikes
            minindex = j
        End If
    Next j
    MsgBox("image" & CStr(images(k).imagename) & "has the most dislikes with " & CStr(min))
End Sub
```

should be

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim max, maxindex, i As Integer
    max = images(1).likes
    maxindex = 1
    For i = 1 To k
        If max < images(i).likes Then
            max = images(i).likes
            maxindex = i
         End If
     Next i
     MsgBox("image " & CStr(images(maxindex).imagename) & " has the Most likes with" & CStr(max))
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim min, j, minindex As Integer
    minindex = 1
    min = images(1).dislikes
    For j = 1 To k
        If min > images(j).dislikes Then
            min = images(j).dislikes
            minindex = j
        End If
    Next j
    MsgBox("image" & CStr(images(minindex).imagename) & "has the most dislikes with " & CStr(min))
End Sub
```